# Irreducibility of $x^{n}+x+1$

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, galois-theory, factoring

Motivated by [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264801/prove-that-for-any-nonnegative-integer-n-the-number-55n1-55-n-1), and [KCd's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264801/prove-that-for-any-nonnegative-integer-n-the-number-55n1-55-n-1/264806#comment578528_264806) on my answer, I am left with the following question:

> **Question:** Suppose that $n\not \equiv 2\pmod{3}$.  Is $$x^n+x+1$$ irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$?

I am not sure how to solve this, any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: This is clearly false, we have $x^{4}+x+1=(x+1) \left(x^3-x^2+x+1\right)$

Comment: Your RHS is $x^4+2x+1$. I verified this for $n\leq 100$ in sage.

Comment: @user32240 What you have is incorrect. $(-1)^4 + (-1) + 1 = 1$

Comment: I see. But I believe now I found one.

Comment: Sorry ignored the modulo condition given.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it is true. See the second claim of [Theorem 1 on page 289](http://www.mscand.dk/article.php?id=1472).

Comment: I found this by Googling "x^n+x+1 irreducible" which led me to [this mathoverflow link](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/56506/irreducibility-of-some-trinomials-modulo-p).

Comment: Very nice, thank you.

Comment: +1. Improvement suggestion: Add the word "Yes" to the answer.